# i am confused about j2ee and php

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee

As a developer going through web development I would like to know if `J2EE` or `PHP` is better for building web sites.

My initial thoughts were that J2EE was better because it is `Java` based but upon reading several articles I read that PHP might be easier and more focused with regard to web development.

On this topic I have another query, whilst looking at different articles on web design and construction I came across websites that claimed to be built in **J2EE, Java and Ruby**. Is J2EE the same as Java? Or is it something completely different.

Comment: PHP would be a better choice as its widely used. Also, its easier to code using PHP. "The best things in using PHP are that it is extremely simple for a newcomer, but offers many advanced features for a professional programmer."

Comment: there are many answers to it, php is easy to write, j2ee is not, php is dynamic typed language and interpretted not compiled so, not suitable for high scalability, j2ee(standards + java web application) is compiled then interpreted, so faster, many enterprises use this over php.

Comment: Ideally Java is used for large scale complex applications where PHP is good for Mid Scale and Small scale Apps. But its not a hard rule. Facebook has been using PHP only.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing a lot more about your project, _e.g._, what are the lots of features you're talking about, where are you developing it and with what potential developers to help you with it, what are your hosting and operations options? It's a very broad question, and, as with many broad questions, there's no one size fits all answer.

Comment: @VivekVermani That's pretty much untrue. AFAIK, FB uses PHP for frontend only, and the backend systems are mainly Java-based (along with some other platforms of course). Other than that, you're kinda right; PHP is suitable mostly for mid- and small scale applications and is the preferred platform for hobbyists while J2EE fits larger scale, complex, industrial-quality applications better. I'd rather not touch an EJB application, however, a I'd choose Java (Enterprise) with Spring MVC over PHP in any case. Problem is, you have nearly zero chance to find a free webhost for Java-based webapps

Comment: First of all think that what do you want to do? A career or just a task? If you want to get money in your career choose java and spend years to stay in this field. But if you want quick earning money and complete projects in one or two days choose PHP. Never think that if something is hard and tricky then you must go to that way but think that what others are doing and where others are rushing to?

Comment: This depends on your needs, your favorite language and if you would like to follow standards for WebServices for example or have a standard for accessing different database vendors.. and also if your application is on a high complexity level, then choose or learn J2E or JavaEE6/7.Also you said, you have knowlage in Java, then you'll maybe be faster in developing JEE Apps then PHP once, but PHP is also very interesting and nice to lern and work with it. So now it's your choice ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no J2EE anymore. There is Java EE. One *profile* in Java EE is the [web profile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-web-downloads-1956240.html). So while Java EE has a bunch of complex, enterprise-level stuff in it, you just use the piece you need.

However, it isn't even like Java EE is *the* choice for developing web applications in Java. It is the standard, but people have enjoyed great success with open-source frameworks like [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). If you expand your scope beyond Java to all JVM languages, you have [Grails](http://grails.org/) (in Groovy) and [Play](http://www.playframework.com/) (in Java but also in Scala) at your disposal as well. Both are extremely good.

And then there are so many other non-JVM options like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/about/) (PHP) as you say but also Rails, Django (Python), etc.

So to truly appreciate what's "better," you need to consider a lot of things:

- Your comfort and productivity with the language
- Your comfort and productivity with the "ecosystem"--*i.e.* accessing third-party libraries to help you with various tasks, ease of mocking and testing, boilerplate code and mundane tasks being abstracted away, ease of implementing caching and minifying web assets, etc.
- Ability to find help online through a vibrant community
- Your requirements. If you need to access Amazon S3 buckets, for example, and your language or third-parties libraries in that language have poor S3 support, you should avoid it. Similarly, if you need to use Neo4J as a data store but there is poor support, move on.

There is no "right" answer to this question. I would suggest the options approach described in [Lean Software Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321150783). Do some research to narrow your choices to three. Then get a site up and implement a representative feature *with all three choices*. The less appropriate choices for you will eliminate themselves and leave the best choice for you.

As for your last question, Java is a programming language; Java EE is an enterprise software platform utilizing the Java language and the JVM (with multiple profiles as mentioned). The Ruby part of the application you mentioned was probably utilized with [JRuby](http://jruby.org/), which enables you to run Ruby on the JVM via [JSR 223](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223).

Comment: is javaEE support open source , actually i don't want to work on asp,net cause it is high price , i want open source , java is good or php is better ?

Comment: Keep in mind that "open-source" and "no cost" commonly go together but don't mean the same thing. But you can develop in Java EE and PHP without cost. The JVM frameworks I mentioned--Spring MVC, Grails, Play--are all open-source. So is Zend for PHP web development.

Answer (score 0):

this is depend on you skill or understability if you have good configuration knowledge then i suggest to you got through java j2ee. php is more easy to java

Comment: can i study j2ee then study php ?

Comment: are u fresher or experienced person?

Comment: i am experinced person in desktop developing

Comment: but in web i am new in this topic

Comment: so i suggest, you can go with php it is easy learning programming language,and less configuration But java is hard. now can decide.

Comment: Dear no more discussion its depend your capability.

Answer (score -1):

To be short and concise, If we're talking about *professional* development, then Java is the way to go.

If you're a hobbyist, then PHP would most probably be the right choice of yours.